# How to call through pointer-to-member function saved in a container?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, member-functions, function-call, class-members

I am trying to write a member function that calls other member functions of the same object in turn until one of them works.

I would like to write this as below:

```
class myClass
{
   bool A() { return false; }
   bool B() { return false; }
   bool C() { return false; }
   bool D() { return false; }
   void doIt() 
   {
      const QList<bool (myClass::*) ()> funcs({
                      &myClass::A, &myClass::B, &myClass::C, &myClass::D
         });

      bool result(false);
      for (auto iter = funcs.cbegin(); !result && iter != funcs.cend(); ++iter) 
      {
         result = this->(*iter) ();
      }
   }
};
```

But I can not get the syntax right to call my function through the iterator. qt-creator displays the error

```
called object type 'bool (myClass::*)()' is not a function or function pointer
```

pointing to the second opening bracket, and g++ reports

```
must use .* or ->* to call pointer-to-member function
```

pointing to the second close bracket, both in the line where I assign to result in the DoIt member function. (Note that the example operators in the g++ error message are enclosed within grave accents, but the markup drops the "*" if I include them.)

I can find any number of examples of how to call through pointers to member functions, but nothing with this combination of saving the pointers-to-member-function in a collection and calling in `this`

Comment: Does `this->*(*iter) ()` work?

Comment: No. Both QtCreator and g++ give the same error.

Comment: See also https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#macro-for-ptr-to-memfn

Comment: Using an intermediate variable `bool (myClass::*mfn) () = *iter;` (or `auto mfn = *iter`) is really helpful to make code readable and then simply syntax to call member function: `(this->*mfn)();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the priority binding for the `()` operator, you need to add some more parens:

```
result = (this->*(*iter))();
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a million. That syntax is pretty weird, I'm not surprised I couldn't work it out for myself.

Comment: `this->* *iter)()` would be enough parenthesis. However, for better readability, one could use a temporary variable: `auto mfn = *iter; (this->*mfn)()`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the *@1201ProgramAlar*m 's answer, if you have access to the [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) compiler, you could able to avoid the weird syntax, by using the [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) from `<functional>` header.

```
#include <functional> // std::invoke

result = std::invoke(*iter, this);
```

Comment: Thank you too; I look forward to getting my hands on a `c++17` compiler.